# C - how to determine how bits are stored

Tags: c, struct, unsigned, bit-fields

I've been learning a bit about bit fields and how they're stored
The struct below partitions a 32 bit unsigned int into 3 components: x, y and z.

```
struct bit_num {
    unsigned int x : 4,
                 y : 8,
                 z :20;
}
```

So the compiler determines how the fields will be placed within the unsigned int, and it's one of the 2:

[ x(4 bits) ][   y(8 bits)   ][          z(20 bits)           ]

or

[          z(20 bits)           ][   y(8 bits)   ][ x(4 bits) ]

My question is how do I determine using the struct above which of the 2 layouts is being used here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should only use bitfields when order of the bits doesn't matter. C standard has defined bitfields fairly poorly, and gives compilers lot of leeway to implement them. This makes writing portable order dependent bitfield code very hard.

Comment: *I've been learning a bit about bit fields and how they're stored*  And when you use a different compiler, you have to throw away everything you've learned.  Bit fields are almost entirely "implementation-defined", which means they are almost entirely non-portable.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it into the union with the 4velements unsigned char array. In the program set one of the bitfields to the known value. Print the array and you will know.

Nothing else needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `union` to analyze the layout of the bit-fields.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct bit_num {
    unsigned int x : 4,
                 y : 8,
                 z :20;
};

union bit_layout
{
    unsigned int w;
    struct bit_num b;
    unsigned char c[sizeof(unsigned int)];
};

int main(void)
{
    union bit_layout bl = { .b = { .x = 0xF, .y = 0xA5, .z = 0xC800C } };
    printf(".x = 0x%X, .y = 0x%.2X, .z = 0x%.5X, .w = 0x%.8X\n",
           bl.b.x, bl.b.y, bl.b.z, bl.w);
    printf("c[0] = 0x%.2X, c[1] = 0x%.2X c[2] = 0x%.2X, c[3] = 0x%.2X\n",
           bl.c[0], bl.c[1], bl.c[2], bl.c[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

On a Mac running macOS 10.13.6 with GCC 8.2.0, I get the output:

```
.x = 0xF, .y = 0xA5, .z = 0xC800C, .w = 0xC800CA5F
c[0] = 0x5F, c[1] = 0xCA c[2] = 0x00, c[3] = 0xC8
```

So, the `.x` member of the bit-field is stored in the least significant nybble; the `.y` member is stored in the next 2 nybbles; and the `.z` member is stored in the 5 most significant nybbles.  However, the byte layout shows that the byte of the array with index 0 holds the `.x` and the less significant half the `.y` value; the byte with index 1 holds the more significant half of the `.y` value and the least significant nybble of the the `.z` value, and the remaining two bytes of the array contain the rest of the `.z` value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example program.

```
struct bit_num {
    unsigned int x : 4,
                 y : 8,
                 z :20;
};

struct bit_num bm = {0x1, 0x23, 0x45678};

void main()
{
}
```

Compile it and use `objdump -d -j .data a.out` to dump the `.data` section.

```
000000000060102c <bm>:
  60102c:       31 82 67 45
```

The bytes from low address to high address are `31 82 67 45`. Because the most significant bit (aka [MSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Most_significant_bit)) in binary number is the left-most bit, we write these four bytes from **high address to low address**:

```
45 67 82 31
```

Then we convert them to binary numbers:

```
01000101 01100111 10000010 00110001
```

This binary number can be grouped as follows:

```
MSB -------------------------- LSB
01000101011001111000 00100011 0001
(20bits)             (8bits)  (4bits)
z=0x45678            y=0x23   x=0x1
```

Then you can know that `x`, `y` and `z` are placed in an `unsigned int` from [LSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Least_significant_bit) to [MSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Least_significant_bit).